# echo items from mysqli_fetch_array into html table td tags not showing up

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, echo

Here is my code, I get the  items to show but nothing will echo in the  tags. I tried just removing the php echo statements and just try writing in some text but still nothing. Thanks in advance

```
    <?php
//Create a connection
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'bachi619', 'company');

//check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect)){
    echo 'Failed to connecto to database'.mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM employees");
?>

<br>
    <table width="500", cellpadding=5 callspacing=5 border=1>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    <?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['first_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['last_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['department']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>



    </table>
```

Comment: put this ahead of the script to see what happens.    ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: It might just be a mistake when you pasted the code here, but you don't have any `<?php ?>` tags around the first block of PHP code

Comment: close your php tag before you start the table declaration

Comment: sorry I just updated my code, looks like there was an error when I tried to copy and paste my code, I just updated it with the not working code I am using.

Comment: `print_r($result);` to make sure that the query is actually returning data

Comment: [See my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053712/echo-items-from-mysqli-fetch-array-into-html-table-td-tags-not-showing-up#comment31656560_21053747) about the syntax errors below. @user2684521

Comment: Just added the following block of code right under the $result variable declaration  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $rows['first_name']. " " . $rows['last_name']. '<br>';
    
} it outputs the data I am trying to grab and that block works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing PHP in several places:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '11111', 'company');
if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect)){
echo 'Failed to connecto to database'.mysqli_connect_error();}


$result= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM employees");
?>
 <table width="500", cellpadding=5 callspacing=5 border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
<?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['first_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['last_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['department']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>



</table>
```

Comment: That was strange looks like there was an issue when I pasted my code on my original post. I just updated it and it now has the the code that I am trying to use but is not working.

Comment: **Two syntax errors:** Comma in `<table width="500", cellpadding=5 callspacing=5 border=1>` and a typo in the word `callspacing` instead of `cellspacing` should read as `<table width="500" cellpadding=5 cellspacing=5 border=1>`

Comment: Thanks, I didnt see that at all. Just updated that but still no luck with the echo statements.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure there is indeed data in your table/columns, taking notice of letter-case etc. `first_name` and `First_Name` are `two different animals` altogether. Personally, I wouldn't do it this way. @user2684521

Comment: Thanks I did check to see if there is data in the tables and columns and there is, I can echo them out if I write this code under the $result declaration while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $rows['first_name']. " " . $rows['last_name']. '<br>';
    
}

Comment: still though for some reason I cant echo out the data in the <td>. I tried removing the echo statement from the <td> and just write in text but not even that shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue. At first I thought mysqli_fetch_array() couldn't work inside  tag. But now it finally did. Anyways, after checking your codes have you tried removing the : in `<?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>`
Because as far as I know you don't need a ; or a : if you're calling a function inside `while-loop` or any `loop function`.
Try this:
`while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`